# Numerically differentiating a function online using an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

So from what I understand ODEs are Turing complete. So I should be able to differentiate a function $g(t)$ online using an ODE. By online I mean, that at each time $t$ I only have the value of $g(t)$ available, so I need the ODE to somehow remember older values in the ODE if they are needed.

I am not sure if this would work only for numerical differentiation, that is by approximating $f'(t)$ by $\frac{f(t)-f(t-h)}{h}$ or if I could also even approximate $f'(t)$ more directly.

So essentially, I am looking for an ODE of the form $$\frac{dx}{dt}=F(x_1(t),x_2(t),x_3(t),\ldots,x_n(t),f(t),t)$$ such that there is some function $$G(x_1(t),x_2(t),x_3(t),\ldots,x_n(t),f(t),t)$$ of the $x_i$ that is approximately equal to $f'(t)$.

So far, I have been able to show that if I just set $\frac{dx_1}{dt}+x_1=f(t)$, this implies $$x_1(t)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i f^{(i)}(t),$$ so I could just define $$G(x_1(t),f(t),t)=f(t)-x_1(t)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (-1)^{i+1} f^{(i)}(t).$$ But this would contain all the higher order derivatives in addition to $f'$ and I cannot figure out how to get rid of them.

If I try to repeat this approach, e.g. by setting $\frac{dx_2}{dt}+x_2=x_1$, then I can get various linear combinations of the $f^{(i)}$ but I cannot get anything that would approximately resemble any series I know, e.g. a Taylor series or something similar.

Is this at all possible or does this approach not work?

*Edit* Some more context of where this is coming from:

There is an idea in some areas of cognitive modeling that certain cognitive functions can be described by ODEs that try to minimize some perceptive inputs. I.e. the idea is that there is no other memory required except the state of these ODEs. However, the ODEs often use derivatives of some inputs, and thus to support this claim these derivatives would either have to be computed as part of an ODE, or there is still some other state except the ODE state left that remembers previous values.

Example: If I just try to minimize the change in the angle to some moving object, I would automatically track the movement of that object. This would also work much better than just minimizing the angle itself, as the change in angle also incorporates the movement of the object relative to my movement. But then I would either have to compute the derivative of the angle by remembering previous values or use some ODE that would allow me to estimate the current change of angle.

Comment: I'm just guessing, what your collection of keywords comes closest to is automatic differentiation and especially the forward propagation of truncated Taylor series. There indeed the ODE for the elementary functions are used to reduce evaluation of Fa di Bruno formulas to variations of convolutions/Cauchy products of the complexity of a truncated series multiplication. // Other associations are the Lie theory of ODE and differential algebra (algebra with derivation operators).

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you for your ideas. I tried to edit the question to give some more context. The main idea is if it is possible to compute the derivative of $f$ if at any time $t$ we only have $f(t)$ available (i.e. online) and cannot store previous values except as an ODE state. That is, $f(t)$ serves as an input to an ODE at each time. So algorithmic differentiation is not what I am looking for, as this would need a complete representation of $f(t)$ that we can differentiate. However, my question is about finding out how little representation is actually needed.